# How to get the binding expression inside a BindingHandler in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

Lets say I have a bound span

```
<span data-bind="MyBinding: Name"></span>
```

And I have a custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.MyBinding = {
   init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
        // I want to get the string "Name" here. NOT the value of Name.
   },
};
```

How do i get a string with the value of the binding expression inside the handler? ie how do i get "Name" not "Value of name".

I also need the expression so passing the string "Name" is not feasible.

```
<span data-bind="MyBinding: 'Name'"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Knockout *does* have a built-in way to do this. You do need to adapt your custom binding a little (namely, it becomes an object instead of a string value). Knockout allows you, along with the `init` and `update` properties, to specify a `preprocess` property. For example, suppose we have the following viewModel:

```
var app = { data: ko.observable('Hello World') };
```

And a simple binding that would convert the string passed to it fully to lowercase, and output both the binding's name and value (the property passed in the view obviously being `data`):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.lower = {
  update: function(elem, value) {
    var obj = ko.unwrap(value());
    elem.textContent = 'Name: ' + ko.unwrap(obj.name) + 
      ' - Value: ' + ko.unwrap(obj.data).toLowerCase();
  },
  preprocess: function(value, bindingName) {
    return '{data:' + value + ', name:\'' + bindingName + '\'}';
  }
};
```

It's as simple as stringifying the `value` property passed to it & transforming the binding's value into an object with 2 keys (name & value here). [Have a look](http://jsbin.com/gimilipuxo/edit?html,js,output). See [Binding preprocessing](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in `Name` as string and not as a reference:

```
<span data-bind="MyBinding: 'Name'"></span>

ko.bindingHandlers.MyBinding = {
   init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
        var myBinding = valueAccessor(); // will contain 'Name';
        var valueOfmyBinding = viewModel[myBinding]; //value of the Name property
   },
};
```

You can still use your expression as a string because in Javascript you can [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) altough `eval()` is a dangerous function: here is a sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Yvu/).

Or if you only need to support simple property expression like `Child.Name` you can write your own parser where you split the string on the dots and foreach on the accessors.

Comment: How will this work if it is a complex expression. eg "Child.Name"

Comment: Why the string won't work for you? In JavaScript you can `eval` basically any string into JS code.

Comment: Or you if you have this basic expressions like `Child.Name` you can write your own parser. Just split on the dot and foreach on the accessors.

Comment: @Simon a small sample with eval http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Yvu/. Al tough I would go for the custom parsing because eval can be very dangerous.

Comment: Is there still not a native way to do this, without calling into `viewModel` or `bindingContext.$data[]`.  I am doing the same thing, and thankfully I only need the simple expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, so you won't need the eval.

```
<span data-bind="MyBinding: 'Name.More.AndMore'"></span>

ko.bindingHandlers.MyBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();

        var sp = value.split('.');
        var current = viewModel;
        for(var i=0;i<sp.length;i++) {
            var nNode = current[sp[i]];
            if ( nNode ) {
                current = nNode;
            }
        }
        $(element).html(current());
    }
};
```

As [nemesv](/questions/tagged/nemesv) already explained, you need to give the Name as string value in your binding. After that you can use this to step through your viewmodel to retrieve the value. To display the value in the element I've added
    `$(element).html(current());`
Here the `current()` is at the deepest level in my viewmodel so it can be called and the return value can be used to update the html.

Comment: Can you describe what "the following" is? Why does it answer the question? You can [edit] your answer to include a description.

Comment: I just expanded the answer @nemesv gave. By the following I mean the following piece of code

Answer (score 1):

I propose to transfer the name of the property with use another binding.

```
<div data-bind="myBinding: content, nameOfProp:'content'"></div>

ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
      var nameOfProp = allBindings.get("nameOfProp");
    };
  }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Yvu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I like what pavel-chervov said above. In a similar vein if you don't mind using a bit of jQuery:

```
<span data-binding-name="Name" data-bind="MyBinding: Name"></span>

ko.bindingHandlers.MyBinding = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
        var nameOfProp = $(element).data('binding-name');
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party on this, but here's what I did, and it works like a charm:

JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myHandler = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var regex = /return ([^\s]+)\s*}/;

        //accessor will contain whatever expression was used in data-bind
        //so in this example it will be "myProp.childProp"
        var accessor = regex.exec(valueAccessor.toString())[1];

        //...
},
//...
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="myHandler: myProp.childProp"></div>
```

So the value of accessor (in case you missed the comment) will be "myProp.childProp"